# VB.net using delegates to show received data

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I still didn't got it. It seems very easy, but it doesn't work. 
I original have a "show received data problem" in my application. Because I'm not sure, if I got the issue right, I downseized it. Now I try with a delegate to a textbox just to show the received data.
Please: this is a get the issue understanding problem, I of course read many articles of this, and only because it doesn't work I post it now here.

I did the following:

In my `MSCom_DataReceived` method I declarated as follows:

```
Dim MeineAusgabe As Form_Dashboard.TextBox2_Delegate
```

In my class Form_Dashboard the definition is like this:

```
Public Delegate Sub TextBox2_Delegate(ByVal msg As String)
```

My `MSCom_DataReceived` method calls the delegate:

```
MeineAusgabe = AddressOf Form_Dashboard.PrintData
MeineAusgabe.Invoke(buffer)
```

And here is PrintData:

```
Public Sub PrintData(ByVal sdata As String)
    Me.TextBox2.Text = sdata
End Sub
```

If I debug this code, the received data goes to TextBox2, but in my Form while running, I can't see it.
It seems really easy, so I hope somebody can send me to the right way.

Comment: It is a very traditional bug caused by the horrid VB.NET default instance feature.  Form_Dashboard is a *type*, not the instance of the form object that you are looking at.  Deadly when used in a thread, you get another instance of the form, one whose Show() method was never called.  You have to use the proper reference.

Comment: ok, I understand that, but how shall I do this exactly?

Comment: if I use it directly, without building a delgate it won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It works with an own thread and delgate. Interesting, it doesn't work with different modules. After I copied the modul which does the receiving in my form class, it works. That's not very satisfying.